# Unable to build Spark 1.5.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, compiling

I am newbie to Linux, Ubuntu, spark. Trying to install local Spark 1.5.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS memory 19.3GiB Disk 7.5GB 64bit.

I get error during the build of Spark:

```
[Error] Could not create directory /home/peter/spark-1.5.2/unsafe/target/streams/compile/$global/$global/discoveredMainClasses
```

I installed Java with following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-respository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

I installed Scala using following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/src/scala
sudo tar -xvf scala-2.11.7.tgz -C /usr/local/src/scala/
```

I edited `.bashrc`:

```
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/src/scala/scala-2.11.7
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I installed Git

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

I installed Spark:

```
tar -xvf spark-1.5.2.tgz
sbt/sbt assembly
```

I also tried `build/sbt assembly`, `sudo stb/stb assembly`, `sudo build/sbt assembly`.  This is where I get error.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie myself and ran into same issue. Try running `chown` command and get ownership of the `spark-1.5.2` folder

```
cd /home/peter
sudo chown peter -R spark-1.5.2
```